# Efficient MySQL Query Method to avoid multiple OR statement

Tags: mysql

I am quite new about queries and I would like to know if there is an easier solution for the query I am working on.

For instance I want to get the data where x is 5,7,9,11,13,15 and 17.

I have a query like below;

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE x = 5 or x = 7 or x = 9 or x = 11 or x = 13 or x = 15 or x = 17;
```

Is it okay to use this query or are there any other simpler and efficient solution?

**EDIT**

Does it affect the perfomance when I use x=[5,7,8,11,13,15,17] vs x=[5,11,7,15,8,17,13]

X is the ID of another category for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is shorter but performs equally

```
SELECT * FROM abc WHERE x in (5,7,9,11,13,15,17)
```

But remember if one entry in the `in` clause is `null` then it returns FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will search about benchmarking and try it myself. By the way, off topic what would you suggest me if I want output to become randomly instead of recent to old?

Comment: `order by rand()`